# Broken links on terms list page

Tags: register-taxonomy

I've registered a custom taxonomy for a custom post type. Every term on the admin term list page has a link to the list of posts filtered by that term.

[image]

This link should look like this:

for a custom post type:

.../edit.php?taxonomy-name=taxonomy-term-name&post_type=post-type-name

for posts:

.../edit.php?taxonomy-name=taxonomy-term-name

However, for my taxonomy the links do not have the post_type argument, resulting in links like `.../edit.php?taxonomy-name=taxonomy-term-name` which makes the links lead to regular `posts` list filtered by a term of a taxonomy they don't have. I can't figure out why this is.

My code:

```
//register a post type in a plugin
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_tdlrm_store_item', 10 );
function register_post_type_tdlrm_store_item() {
    $labels  = array(
        //omitted
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Store items', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'store-category' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-cart',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,   
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'product')
    );

    $args = apply_filters('tdlrm_filter: tdlrm_store_item: alter register_post_type arguments', $args);

    register_post_type( 'tdlrm_store_item', $args );

}

//register taxonomy in another plugin
add_action( 'init', 'register_ingredients_taxonomy', 99);
function register_ingredients_taxonomy(){
        $labels = array(
            //omitted
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'public'            => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => false,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'ingredient' ),
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'tdlrm_ingredients', array( 'tdlrm_store_item' ), $args );
    }

//I tried to fix the situation
add_filter('tdlrm_filter: tdlrm_store_item: alter register_post_type arguments', 'alter_post_type_arguments');
function alter_post_type_arguments($arguments){
        if(!in_array('tdlrm_ingredients', $arguments['taxonomies'])){
            $arguments['taxonomies'][] = 'tdlrm_ingredients';
        }

        return $arguments;
    }
```

I don't understand why this gives me wrong links.
Also, I have re-saved permalinks just in case, to no effect.

**Update**

I get to the term list page via a custom link in a sub-menu. The link have been added like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_link', 50);
function add_menu_link(){
        add_submenu_page(
            'TDLRM',
            'Ingredients',
            'Ingredients',
            'edit_posts',
            'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=tdlrm_ingredients',
            ''
        );
    }
```

Comment: How are you even getting to this screen if `show_in_menu` is `false` for the post type?

Comment: I tried your code, and it worked well for me - the "Count" URL looked like `https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?tdlrm_ingredients=<slug>&post_type=tdlrm_store_item`. So maybe you can try deactivating plugins (or your other custom code) and/or switching to a default theme?

Comment: I also tried removing the `$args = apply_filters('tdlrm_filter: tdlrm_store_item: alter ...', $args);`, and the links still had the `post_type` parameter in the query string.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I wanted the link to this post type to appear as a child of another menu item, so I coupled `'show_in_menu' => false` with `add_submenu_page()` to 'move' it.

Comment: @SallyCJ, thank you for helping out. I never thought it might be a plugin or theme conflict.

Comment: So, have you resolved the issue? Was it really a plugin/theme conflict? Also, regarding 'moving' that menu item, you could actually set `show_in_menu` to the slug of a top-level menu page added via `add_menu_page()` - but be sure to read the (1st) note [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_menu).

Comment: @SallyCJ, actually I just tried deactivating most of plugins (my theme, too) and it didn't work. Also, I placed the `register_taxonomy( 'tdlrm_ingredients' <...>)` into the function that adds another taxonomy that has correct links. And made arguments identical for both of them. Didn't work either. Then, I changed the taxonomy slug, replaced its underscore with a dash, no use.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks for a cool tip on `show_in_menu`. As for the first note you mentioned, 'If this isn’t desired, the plugin that creates the menu page needs to set the add_action priority for admin_menu to 9 or lower' sounds like I have to set priority on the action that adds my post type or taxonomy. If it is so, this may cause conflicts later on.

Comment: There is that condition, `if ( 'post' !== $post_type ){}` on line 46 of edit-tags.php that checks what post type the taxonomy belongs to. Strangely, in the case of my taxonomy `$post_type` equals 'post'

Comment: Yet in the same file, `$tax->object_type` is `['tdlrm_store_item']

Comment: When reading through the WP_Terms_List_Table class, I got it. I had this code: `add_submenu_page('TDLRM','Ingredients','Ingredients', 'edit_posts','edit-tags.php?taxonomy=tdlrm_ingredients','');`. When I added post_type parameter to the menu slug (like this: `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=tdlrm_ingredients&post_type=tdlrm_store_item`), the links became correct and ` $post_type` in edit-tags.php is now `tdlrm_store_item`. Strange, though. Getting a post type from the taxonomy's own object that is accessible on this very page seems to me a more logical thing for WP developers to do.

Comment: But a taxonomy can be attached to two or more post types, so that's why, if you omitted the `show_in_menu` arg, or set it to `true`, then you'd see the `post_type` parameter in the URL of the `edit-tags.php` link for the `tdlrm_ingredients` taxonomy under your post type's admin menu. So, you should just always set the `post_type` parameter in the URL.

Comment: As for this - "*If it is so, this may cause conflicts later on*" - I'm not sure what conflicts would arise, but you could do something like `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'func1', 9 ); add_action( 'init', 'func2' );` where `func1` will add your admin menus, whereas `func2` will register your CPT and/or taxonomy. So as you could see, `func1` has a priority of `9`, instead of `10` (the default), and that's what that 1st note meant.

Comment: @SallyCJ My plugin creates a sub-menu. Its addons add links there. In one instance, I wanted a link (plugin settings page) to show up at the very end of sub-menu, so I set priority of the respective action to 30. Similarly, what if I set register_post_type() priority low to make use of `'show_in_menu' => 'somewhere'`, then set higher priority on another post_type-related action? Like adding a taxonomy for that post type. I'd then have to forever keep track of the priorities of register_post_type(). Or am I missing something? Anyway, it's amazing how you always know such details )

Comment: @SallyCJ as for the links, thanks for your explanation. You wanna make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done, @Artem. And as for that "track" thing, I see it now, and so, just use `add_submenu_page()` then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, for my taxonomy the links do not have the post_type argument

Yes, and it's because that argument does not exist in your submenu slug or relative URL (the 5th parameter for [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)), therefore WordPress would not know that you're targeting your post type, and WordPress also would not add that argument to the links for filtering posts by your taxonomy at `wp-admin/edit.php`.

Remember that **taxonomies can be attached to *two or more post types***, hence you should always include the `post_type` argument in your submenu link, even if your taxonomy will only ever going to have one post type. Because when that argument is missing or not specified, WordPress will not default to using the only post type attached to a taxonomy having just one post type attached.

So make sure to include that argument, just like WordPress [does it](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/menu.php#L152) when `show_in_menu` is not specified or is set to `true`:

```php
add_submenu_page(
    'TDLRM',
    'Ingredients',
    'Ingredients',
    'edit_posts',
    'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=tdlrm_ingredients&post_type=tdlrm_store_item',
    ''
);
```

### Additional Notes

1. As I commented, you could actually set `show_in_menu` to the slug of a top-level menu page added using [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), but you would want to use 9 or lower as the action's priority as in `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'your_function', 9 )`. [More details here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_menu) (see the 1st note)

   And if that's not preferred (e.g. because you want another submenu item as the first one, but you need to use 10 or more as the action's priority), then just use `'show_in_menu' => false` and manually call `add_submenu_page()` to add your post type as a submenu of your admin menu.

Comment: finally I got it! I completely overlooked that not only post types can have multiple taxonomies, but taxonomies can have multiple post types, and multiple post type submenus would have dedicated links to the same taxonomy, every such link leading _to the same page_. For the system to know in what post_type context we are dealing with our taxonomy, the post_type get parameter is used.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm glad you could come up with such a comprehensive summary 

Comment: All thanks to your answer Sally CJ. Have a great day!